# How to export a schema from a module in order to use it in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two modules: `book` and `club`. I have a mongoose schema used in the book module which contains some info. I would like to export it and use it as a filed in the club schema. 
The is to access the books read in the `book` module from the `club` module.

bookModule

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Book Schema //Just for the application
var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    genre:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
    },

    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
```

clubModule:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var clubSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    booksRead:{
       //Here, I am trying to use the information used in the bookSchema Module.
    }, 


});
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html I think this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's exactly it!!!! Thanks, mate